# Position button on top of an image which is styled with object-fit: contain

Tags: css, reactjs

The issue might be trivial but since I am new to react I have no clue how to continue.
What I want to achieve: I have an image gallery and when clicking on a specific image I open the detail view of this image by using the following "ImageModal":

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './ImageModal.css';

const ImageModal = ({ imageUrl, onClose }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(true);
  }, []);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsActive(false);
  };

  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    if (!isActive) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`image-modal-overlay ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
      onClick={handleClose}
      onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
    >
      <div className={`image-modal-content ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
        <div className="enlarged-image-container">
          <img className="enlarged-image" src={imageUrl} alt="Enlarged" />
          <span className="close-button" onClick={handleClose}>
            &times;
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ImageModal.propTypes = {
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default ImageModal;
```

and style it with

```
/* ImageModal.css */

.image-modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Start with opacity 0 */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for opacity */
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.image-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  /* Start with scaled-down size */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for transform */
}

.image-modal-overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Apply opacity 1 when active */
}

.image-modal-content.active {
  transform: scale(1);
  /* Apply full scale when active */
}

.enlarged-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.enlarged-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

So what I want to achieve here in terms of layout: Have the image displayed with its natural aspect ratio while fitting within the element's content box. The space around the image is filled with a dark overlay with some opacity and background blur.
And then have a close button be at the top right of each image. And this is the crucial part: From my little understanding "enlarged-image" and "lose-button" are children of "enlarged-image-container" and therefore I would expect the close button with its styling `position: absolute` to be positioned relatively to its closest ancestor (enlarged-image-container).

Maybe the entire layout is too complex for my knowledge to see the necessary changes to be made, but I can't understand why the close button is not placed at the top right corner of each image, but instead seems to have a static position, regardless of the presented image, vertical and horizontal. The images are displayed as expected by maintaining their aspect ratio and filling the space of their container.

Comment: `position: relative;` needs to be on the image container not the image.

Comment: `position: relative;` is already set in the ".enlarged-image-container".

Comment: Then there must be something else going on. Can you show us in a [mcve]?